# Dynamically loading objects from properties file at runtime using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a properties file as such:

`myapp.properties`

```
shape.circle.radius=10
shape.circle.perimeter=63

shape.square.side=10
shape.square.perimeter=40
```

Where circle and square are POJO. How do I construct the circle / square object dynamically? Ideally I want something like this:

```
Circle circle = environment.get("shape.circle");
Square square = environment.get("shape.square");
```

Is there any way I can do it by not reading the properties one by one from the file and loading the objects manually? I can't use SpEL because I know the parameter `circle / square` only at runtime

Comment: How should `environment` construct your objects? I would use the normal Spring mechanism to load properties and then depending on the runtime value create one or the other object.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. Can you please explain how to do that? In my case, I will have the parameter square / circle (which object to create) in my Java code

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create these objects like that:

```
public class Circle {
    private int radius;
    private int perimeter;

    @Autowired
    public Cirlce (
      @Value("${shape.circle.radius}") int radius,
      @Value("${shape.circle.perimeter}") int perimeter) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.perimeter = perimeter;
    }
```

Or even without constructor

```
    @Component
    public class Circle {
        @Value("${shape.circle.radius}"
        private int radius;
    
        @Value("${shape.circle.perimeter}")
        private int perimeter;
     }
```

In this case you will achieve the result you probably want.